# INACCESSIBLE_BOOT_DEVICE when booting Windows 2000 after dual booting with Windows XP

Tags: windows, boot, windows-xp, partitioning, windows-2000

Apparently, I'm having a troubleshoot with both W2K and WXP.

I'll try to summarize: I just got a new PC, and, because it supports both XP and W2K, I had a nice idea to dual boot both of them.

I then created both partitions for W2K & WXP, W2K having 40000GB meanwhile WXP having 80000GB.

Once I installed W2K, it booted just fine. And I managed to install the drivers and etc. However, once I installed WXP (in a different partition), and somehow, W2K stopped booting.

Meanwhile WXP boots normally, W2K gives an "INACCESSIBLE_BOOT_DEVICE" BSoD. I don't know what I did wrong here, I installed both the systems on different partitions however W2K is not booting anymore and instead it is giving me the BSoD.

Comment: would running them on different HDDs and switching between them in bios be an option? Also KGB and KG are... very strange measures of hard disk space

Comment: I'm wondering if it is ever possible dual booting them,  ......  Probably not - simply too old.

Comment: @John It was possible to dual-boot Win98 and Win2000, and it was possible to dual-boot Win98 and WinXP, so I don't immediately see why it wouldn't be possible to dual-boot Win2000 and WinXP on grounds of their age.

Comment: Could be. I have Windows 98 and 95 machines that will not run on anything faster than 2 GHz (known kernel bug in these systems).   That is why I said too old.

Comment: I meant KGB for [number] thousand gigabytes, it is easier to say just the number and KGB rather than thousand gigabytes.

Comment: Why wouldn't you just say "terabytes" instead of wasting the reader's time?

Comment: @John XP was basically 2000 with some improvements - in theory installing alongside 2k *should* work but here it hasn't. Saying its impossible to dualboot cause its too old is  incorrect

Comment: Impossible may have been the wrong work - improbable. Perhaps post a solution to make it work.

Comment: You may want to experiment with it in a Virtual Machine first like using VMWare Player etc and explore what exactly works and what not and then try it out on a real system.

Comment: Mike Shimomura, please avoid inventing your only abbreviations. KGB is already taken:
https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/KGB. "WXP" is another uncommon term. I consider it impolite if you do not take your time to be as precise and understandable as possible. I seriously doubt that your Windows 2000 partition has a size of "40 000 GB" which would be "20 TB". Windows 2000 cannot simply address 20 TB.